# update_columns update a string but it's nil when fetching on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to save file to a Google Storage bucket, I followed [the official guide for rails](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-storage).

So I've this code for updating my file

```
after_create :upload_document, if: :path 

  def upload_document
    file = Document.storage_bucket.create_file \
      path.tempfile,
      "cover_images/#{id}/#{path.original_filename}",
      content_type: path.content_type,
      acl: "public"
    # Update the url to my path field on my database
    update_columns(path: file.public_url)
  end
```

I can store my file on my bucket, I can retrieve the `public_url` and update the path field on my table but when I try to fetch the path string I have a `nil`. Exemple on my rails console

```
Document.find(14) 
=> #<Document id: 14, name: "Test", path: "https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx.x...", created_at: "2018-10-05 07:17:59", updated_at: "2018-10-05 07:17:59">
Document.find(14).path
=> nil
Document.find(14).name
=> "Test"
```

So I don't understand why I can access to my path field on my SQL database after an update using the [update_columns](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns) of Rails.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: what id the model name to update? you see in document on link you provided "user.update_columns(last_request_at: Time.current)"    update.update_columns.  You are updating a field/column of some model not just update_column ? column of which model?  in your case you should have instance of Document model  something like document.update_column ....

Comment: It's update directly the element I'm creating. For exemple from the log of my server : `Document Update (0.4ms)  UPDATE "documents" SET "path" = ? WHERE "documents"."id" = ?  [["path", "https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxxxxx-xxxxxx.appspot.com/cover_images/14/README.md"], ["id", 14]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some method defined on `Document` class (or included module) that is overriding the default attribute accessor.

To find out which, write this in console:

```
Document.find(14).method(:path).source_location
```

In any case you can access directly the attribute with

```
Document.find(14)['path']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. It was indeed override of the same name. I try you patch and it's working great, I also try but changing the name of my attribute and it also resolve my problem.